# Online & offline help system

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

using .NET, I am required to develop an online multi-language help that works like msdn.
and an offline version is also required.

What tools should i use in this regard so that i avoid over working online and offline work.

Comment: By "offline" do you mean a "desktop application?"

Answer (score 0):

Silverlight OOB (Out Of Browser) application would be a choice for your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

If you are about to build your own help system, why not learn from people who already did so. The Software "Help and Manual" or "RoboHelp" (two out of many) has a set of export features of it's help topics. To keep it simple and have an indipendent solution with hight compatibility, i recomend your output should be html. You can deploy the html for offline use and provide a html version for online use. Why not play around with a common help authoring tool and see how they provide their html help in offline mode.

The way to build and maintain your help topics would be a different story. However, if you take the approach of building a html help you might look for a content-management-system to edit your topics.

Comment: i need a dynamic system. that should read content from html files and store to some repository. then The asp.NET mvc website will host that content.